# Как писать на Китайском в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, unicode

Как писать на Китайском в Delphi? (заголовки формы, на кнопках, и т.д)

Answer (score 4):

Delphi 2009 и выше поддерживают Uniсode.
А для версий ниже есть бесплатные компоненты TNTcomponents.

Ну и включить в windows поддержку китайского языка.

Comment: >Ну и включит в виндоусе поддержку китайского языка.
   Тогда моя программа будет корректно работать только у меня, скажем так если её запустят на другом компе то получат ???? или иероглифы.

>Delphi 2009 и выше поддеживают unikode А для версий ниже есть бесплатные >компоненты TNTcomponents
    Юзаю Delphi 7, что можно придумать?

Comment: TNTcomponents  однозначно

Ну а без поддержки языка показывает только латиницу (хотя например кирилица включена по умолчанию). Вот сыллка http://www.axolot.com/TNT/

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:
Найти шрифт, который поддерживает китайский. При создании Формы зарегистрировать этот шрифт в системе, для всех компонентов на форме изменить шрифт на тот, который мы регистрировали.
При уничтожении формы отменить регистрацию шрифта.

Теоретически должно работать.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что будет работать на любой системе. По-моему скромному мнению все равно доставлять в систему "письмо иероглифами" придется.

Answer (score -2):

Используйте шрифты из картинок таким образом вы обеспечите отображение шрифта на любом компьютере, однако это потребует более сложного кода.

Comment: А вы представляйте себе каккая нужна картинка для китайского языка

Comment: Я полагаю что человек который спрашивает знает. Ваш вопрос не актуален.

Comment: Сергей, +1.
Думаю, что еще вариант это рендеринг векторных шрифтов, есть на просторах интернета даже для японского и китайского языков.